# How to get X- oder Y-Coordinate from Scipy mathematical function

Tags: python, scipy, coordinates

When I create a simple mathematical function like..
f(X) = 2*X
using scipy.interpolate - how can I get the X-coordinate of a corresponding Y-coordinate?

Here is the scipy-function:

```
from scipy import interpolate
testfunc = scipy.interpolate.interp1d([1,2], [2,4], kind='linear')
```

I want to get the X-value belonging to Y = 4 (should be 2).
I tried:

```
testfunc.x(4)
```

Comment: I don't - you have f already and since it's linear you have simply f_inv = x/2.  ... so why do you need to get this out of testfunc instead?

Comment: @wim +1. I guess you are probably thinking about a more non-trivial problem, but the way you described it as now is a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to just do reverse interpolation?

```
x,y = ...
testfunc_inverse = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(y, x, kind='linear')
testfunc_inverse(4)
```

Answer (score -1):

I may be missing the point here, however, if you follow the scipy.interpolate.interp1d example you will end up with two numpy arrays of equal length. Seems like you should be able to index the y array against the x array and get your answer. I don't know if you would consider this approach 'pythonic' but it works in this case.